# Is there a better algorithm than shifting elements to left in below array based queue implementation

Tags: c++, queue

I am trying to come up with a design that implements a blocking array queue in C++ similar to Java. I noticed that once the if i keep the front always at index zero of the array then i have to shift elements from index 1 till rear to left in array [ a costly operation ], so that space is available for the queue to insert again at rear.

Is there a better implementation possible for this ? I saw some people having videos on youtube where implementation is to keep moving the front pointer of the queue as elements are dequeued. but then how will you make free space available for insertion as you dequeue from the queue once it is full to capacity?

Please indicate if you still have anything unclear in the question. I am trying to identify if there is a better way than shifting elements to the left which seems unavoidable but inefficient.

[image: A Sample Array based Queue]

Comment: When it matters then we use circular buffers.

Comment: why not wrap `std::queue`/`std::deque`?

Comment: Blocking as in if there is no item to remove from the queue, the thread blocks?

Comment: Yes blocking when no item is there to either take from queue or if queue is full and additional insert is then blocked until space is available from queue.

Comment: You may find [`std::condition_variable`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable) useful for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The optimal way, for production code is to use a std::deque.

If this is an exercise for you to learn, then you could implement a ring buffer. As you describe, you keep two indices: one pointing to the first element of the queue and one pointing to one past the end. Whenever you queue or dequeue, you move one of those indices. The buffer wraps around the end.

When you get to enqueue and need extra space, you need to reallocate a larger buffer. If you do this by doubling the size, on average you'll incur a constant cost (this is called amortized linear).

Comment: Thx guys i implemented using a ring buffer the ArrayBlockingQueue in C++ similar to Java. Except the iterable interface every other feature is present given similar to Java.https://github.com/anandkulkarnisg/ArrayBlockingQueue